# How do we select a Cipher for a TLS 1.2 HttpClient communication in C# (Windows OS)?

Tags: c#, windows, tls1.2

Found `CipherSuitesPolicy` that works in Linux environments. Is there a way to choose cipher on Windows?

```
var sslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                     {
                         CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(new List<TlsCipherSuite> { TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 })
                     };
```

Comment: IIRC, that implementation is only valid in Linux and MacOS. Windows prioritizes the sequence of Cipher Suites provided by the OS based on the SSL/TLS version negotiated. -- That's just an enumeration of the knows Cipher Suites, it doesn't guarantee that the current platform actually supports all of them.

Comment: Is there a tool available for Windows with which TLS1.2 communication can be tested using different ciphers available in Windows?

Comment: You probably need to read [Manage Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls), x System [Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) and [Cipher Suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel) and get [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for a visual test of the transactions. Maybe also get [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (configuration helper)